# Open image inside WebView in new Activity on clicking

Tags: android, webview

Is there a simple way to open an image in new Activity on clicking it inside the webview? 
Or It would be great if I can get the full url of the image on clicking it inside the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, because how should you get the image url ?

it is difficult to get return values from webview events outside the context of webview.

if you have the direct URL of image then you can easily rendered it on UI but without direct URL you can't render an image.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML file

```
<html>
<img src="abc.jpeg" width="100px" >
</html>
```

put it in an assests folder of your android application and load the html in your webview

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");
```

- You can store the image in the assets folder along with the html
  page, and specify the image name as the value of `src` in `img` tag
  in html code,
- or you can give the public URL of the image and the image will be
  renderd on its own

Comment: That I know, I want to get notified when image is clicked inside the webview. I am able to load the image fine.

Comment: Are there multple images in webview

Comment: More than one image.

Comment: Its looking promising. Let me try it.